# Routes behaving weird after update from 3.1 to 6

Tags: routes, .net-6.0, asp.net-mvc-routing, .net-core-3.1

I have updated an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application to .NET 6, and now the routing is causing many "weird" problems.

This used to work:

```
<form asp-route="Resumes.Sections.SetTitle" asp-route-id="@Model.SectionId">            
    <input type="text" name="title" id="formchangetitle">           
</form>
```

Now the url (`asp-route`) is empty. I suspect because the method called also calls for a title (which normally is provided on the post)

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("[area]/{id:guid}/[action]", Name = "Resumes.Home.SetTitle")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SetTitle(Guid id, string title)
```

I also have many `Url.RouteUrl()` calls that used to work, but now also have the same issue as `asp-route`. Some matching of routes is wrong. I have tried many things in the program.cs!

In program.cs is have the following regarding the routes:

```
builder.Services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddNewtonsoftJson();

builder.Services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AppendTrailingSlash = false;
    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
});
```

```
    builder.Services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>{options.ConstraintMap.Add("culture",        typeof(LanguageRouteConstraint));});
```

```
app.UseRouting();
```

```
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Any knows how to get the routes to "match"?

Tried many different route settings in program.cs. Nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up working with the following in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddNewtonsoftJson();

builder.Services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AppendTrailingSlash = false;
    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
});

app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**